# Гомосексуалист or Гомосексуал?

Tags: выбор-слова

Which one is the better term to be used? Is there a difference between two terms? Is the etymology different?

Который из этих терминов больше подходит для использования? Есть-ли между ними разница? Отличается-ли этимология?

Comment: Anybody care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: I can explain, @Volodya - two down-votes means that two members of the community decided that your question is not interesting to a broader audience, nothing less, nothing more. For any native speaker, for example, the answer is obvious.

Besides, the question is poorly formulated. What do you mean by "better"? I imagine that if you'd show some evidence of trying to formulate more thoroughly, it would be less down-vote. E.g. "Аre гомосексуалист and гомосексуал" completely interchangeable? In what context it is more correct to use first form and in what the second one?"

Comment: Наткнулся на слово "гомосексуал" на сайте новостей: "Тьюринг был гомосексуалом. В 1952 году ему предъявили обвинения, поскольку связь с мужчинами преследовалась в то время в Великобритании по закону." https://meduza.io/news/2015/01/28/fray-i-kamberbetch-prizvali-reabilitirovat-osuzhdennyh-za-gomoseksualizm-britantsev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term гомосексуалист (homosexualist) has existed in English language 40 or 50 years ago as well. Today it is considered archaic and possibly a little offensive when used outside of its historical context.

World wide the term is falling into disuse after гомосексуальность (homosexuality) has been declassified from being a psychological disease. As such it was previously called гомосексуализм (homosexualism).

In Russian one can quickly determine the position of the person in relation to the question of equal rights depending on the choice between «гомосексуалист» and «гомосексуал». Those who are supportive of LGBT rights use the latter [1], while the opponents tend to use the former [2]. Apathetic people use whichever they have heard first, but more often the former (due to the nature of Russian speaking society). Neutral groups of people use the latter slightly more often [3].

[1] http://www.gay.ru/science/kon/remark/teacher.html

[2] [http://www.forum.rodnovery.ru/index.php?/topic/4828-гомосексуализм-и-родноверие/](http://www.forum.rodnovery.ru/index.php?/topic/4828-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5/)

[3] [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Гомосексуальность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Within LGBT community the terms «гомосексуализм» and «гомосексуалист» get criticised for being incorrect. -изм and -ист are often used to imply that homosexuals are a political group, and not an arbitrary category of people (with sexuality as the only distinguishing factor). Also due to these terms use in psychiatric literature there is a baggage that comes with their use.

So the choice of a word depends largely on where you come from and what message you are trying to send. If you are in an international setting, even when you speak Russian, you should try to use гомосексуальность and гомосексуал, as these are less likely to cause misunderstanding.

Перевод:

Термин «гомосексуалист» (homosexualist) также существовал и в английском языке 40 или 50 лет назад. Сегодня он считается архаичным и, возможно, немного унизительным при использовании вне исторического контекста.

После деклассификации гомосексуальности (homosexuality) как психологического заболевания, это слово начинает исчезать из речи по всему миру. Как заболевание оно называлось «гомосексуализм» (homosexualism).

В России можно быстро уяснить позицию человека в отношении равноправия по выбору между «гомосексуалист» и «гомосексуал». Те, кто поддерживают права ЛГБТ, пользуются вторым термином [1], в то время как оппоненты употребляют как правило первый [2]. Апатичные в этом вопросе люди используют термин, с которым они столкнулись первым, но чаще первый (в связи с историческим порядком в русско-говорящем обществе). Нейтральные группы немного часто останавливаются на втором из двух слов [3].

[1] http://www.gay.ru/science/kon/remark/teacher.html

[2] [http://www.forum.rodnovery.ru/index.php?/topic/4828-гомосексуализм-и-родноверие/](http://www.forum.rodnovery.ru/index.php?/topic/4828-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5/)

[3] [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Гомосексуальность](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Внутри ЛГБТ сообщества термины «гомосексуализм» и «гомосексуалист» критикуются как неверные. Суффикс изм и ист часто используются для намёка на то, что гомосексуалы формируют политическую группу, а не являются просто произвольной категорией людей (с их сексуальностью, как единственным определяющим фактором). Также, в связи с использованием этих слов в психиатрической литературе, у них остаётся большое количество стигмы.

В связи с этим, выбор слова зависит в основном от того, из какого слоя населения вышел автор, и какие идеи он пытается передать. В международном кругу общения, даже при использовании русского языка, стоит использовать слова гомосексуальность и гомосексуал, в связи с меньшей вероятностью возникновения недопонимания.

Comment: @Artemix по правилам можно отвечать либо на русском, либо на английском и вступать в полемику по этому поводу как минимум некоструктивно. Как и упрекать )

Comment: @shabunc Ну, это был не упрек а совет ). Просто я такой инфы на русском никогда не видел, источники тоже по словам автора англоязычные.

Comment: @Artemix Я постараюсь сегодня перевести, если будет свободное время.

Comment: @Artemix Перевёл. Хоть мне кажется, что лучше было-бы, если кто-то ещё это сделал.

Comment: Кстати, попробовал слова на вкус... Получается так: при восприятии мне всё равно, какое используется на письме или в речи. При этом в своей речи... "гомосексуал" звучит странно, и я не знаю, стал бы я его использовать, если бы был гомосексуалом (слово неприятно звучит, как будто я представитель каких-то конкретных взглядов - "маргинал", "либерал", "наркоман", "протестант"). Вот так странно. Посмотрим, как будет с течением времени.

Comment: Хм. Здесь был мой комментарий про то, что, имхо, дело не столько в «политической» окраске суффикса _-ист_ (которой у него нет вовсе, ср. _филателист_, _специалист_ и т. д.), сколько в попытке «уравнять» гомо- с гетеро- на уровне звучания слов: _гетеросексуал_ (и по-иному не скажешь), но _гомосексуалист_ — дискриминация-с выходит. Куда он делся? Почему пропал бесследно?

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Видел этот ваш комментарий. Потом он пропал. Я решил, что вы его удалили.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько мне известно термина `гомосексуал` в русском языке нет. *Я думаю*, что это разговорное слово и является калькой с английского `homosexual`. [Поисковая выдача](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/31618/%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB) для этого слова по различным словарям показывает различные перенаправляния на второе слово.

Comment: Ну только не калькой. Калька есть заимствование смысла при буквальном переводе облика. Хрестоматийные примеры: ὀρθοδοξία → православие, skyscraper → небоскреб.

Comment: Совершенно не согласен с подходом «Если в словаре нет, значит слова нет». Если завтра в словаре не окажется слова африканец, а будет указано, что я должен использовать негритос, то я «по-словарному» говорить не буду.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov хоть бы скащали что же это, раз не калька. Хотя путать морфологическую передачу с калькой для нелингвиста вполне нормально.

Comment: @Volodya все естественные языки насчитывают сотни тысяч  языковых единиц, которые с каждым годом прибавляют в весе. Естественно никто не способен говорить "по словарю". Тем более любое словарное правило может быть только рекомендацией, а не законом. Мне не известно ни одного случая расстрела за употребление слова "ложить", например.

Comment: @Sugar, это вам стоит сказать, что вы имели в виду под «_я думаю_, что это слово является калькой с английского _homosexual_». Что это прямое заимствование из английского? Нет, здесь никак не потребовалось бы подчеркивать, что это не более чем ваше мнение, ибо это довольно очевидный факт. Что это т. н. варваризм — иноязычное слово не в полной мере усвоенное языком? Не желаю дальше гадать, об’ясните сами, что вы хотели сказать.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov "В технике перевода кальку следует отличать от морфологической передачи, когда иноязычное слово транслитерируется с последующим приспособлением его к морфологии родного языка (для удобства склонения и спряжения). (...) чужое лат. intonatio может быть переведено и калькой («настройка»; от in+tonus), и морфологической передачей («интонация»; чужая транслитерируемая основа «интонац-» + родная флексия «-ия»)."

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov мне неизвестна точная этимология появления этого слова. Калькой назвал по ошибке, т.к. многие слова из моей сферы называют калькированными, хотя на деле являются морфологической передачей.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that the word `гомосекуал` even exist.

It really depends on the context of the talk. In informal talk nobody uses the word `гомосексуалист`. Perhaps `гей`. Or, more probably, other words which have negative meaning and which, I think, are not allowed by the stackexchange rules to be posted here.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with posting swear words if the context demands them. You will see a lot of requests for translating profanity, vulgarity, obscenity, etc. But you're right, this question isn't about it. However, saying that the word doesn't exist when it's in quite a wide useage (wikipedia, etc) is not very productive; as it clearly exists.